# setState in useEffect with state as condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to hide a mobile menu once the pathname changes (using ReactRouter).

The code below shows me a warning because I dont track `mobileOpen` as a dependency. But it works.

```
const Navbar: React.FC<Props> = props => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation()
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mobileOpen) setMobileOpen(false)
    main.current?.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }, [pathname, main])

...
```

As soon as I add it to the dependency array, the code navigation does not open anymore as it would directly trigger the effect and close again.

Is that the correct way of doing it? Would there be a better way of preventing unnecessary renders?

Comment: You could track the previous value of `pathname` in a `useRef` and compare if the pathname has changed.

Comment: Why you need to `mobileOpen`. when you pathname changes your `useEffect` runs automatically?

Comment: yes, it sunr automatically. But I want to not cause a rerender by setting the state to false everytime. Because sometimes it is not false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand from your code, you actually don't need to check if `mobileOpen` is true or not. I guess what you want is setting `mobileOpen` to false no matter what when that effect is triggered. I believe you'll be fine if you update your code like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setMobileOpen(false);
  main.current?.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, [pathname, main])
```

If you still need to check `mobileOpen` has a truthy value for a reason, you can use `setMobileOpen((prevState) => { ... });` syntax too.

Comment: For the pure application logic I do not need to know the state of mobileOpen indeed!
BUT: I want to save some unnecessary renders.
Maybe I have to ask my question differently:

Your code will call setMobileOpen(false) even when mobileOpen already has been false. This will cause the component to rerender. Wouldn't it be better to not rerender unnecessaryly?

Comment: Actually it doesn't rerender if mobileOpen's value doesn't change. It is the case with class components, but useState hook with functional component provides an alternative approach. When you set the same value (=== holds true) to a state, it doesn't trigger a re-render

Comment: You can check this codesandbox to test that: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-re-render-test-q7q3p